# Logon failure trying exec exe on remote machine

Tags: c#, wmi, remote-access

I'm using ManagementClass to execute a exe on remote machine.

```
var serverPath = new ManagementPath
        {
            Server = "SERVERNAME",
            NamespacePath = "\\ROOT\\CIMV2",
            ClassName = "Win32_Process"
        };

        var connection = new ConnectionOptions
        {
            Username = _Domain + @"\" + _UserName,
            Password = _Pass,
            Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
            Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet,

            EnablePrivileges = true,
            Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15)
        };

        var ms = new ManagementScope(serverPath, connection);
        var mprocess = new ManagementClass(ms, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());

        var inParams = mprocess.GetMethodParameters("Create");
        inParams["CommandLine"] = @"F:\Utils\Directory\program.exe";
        inParams["CurrentDirectory"] = @"F:\Utils\Directory\";

        mprocess.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
```

I'm getting the following error from my application:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at KPlusSynchronizer.Tyche.StoreIntoDatabase(String tycheConnection, String sp, XDocument xml, Boolean logXml, String path, String user)
at KPlusSynchronizer.Synchronizer.Synchronize(String tycheTable, String tycheSp, String kplusSp, String path, String user)
```

When I login manually on the server with the same Username and Password as in ConnectionOptions and start the exe manually it works fine.

I've also tried using a ImpersonateUser (that makes me admin, same as Username and Password) before trying to connect.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: Is you process interactive? On which Os is the remote process launched?
Dis solution does not work for interactive processes (Process that interact with UI)

Comment: @ManuelAmstutz The OS is "Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Datacenter". The process is not interactive, but it's making some calls to the database using integrated security in the database...I saw the full error message complains about some Sql. Will update question with full error

Answer (score 0):

I had a look into our code base. We do exactly the same thing with WMI

```
.....
var strWmiPath = string.Format(@"\\{0}\{1}", m_remoteHost, wmiNamespacePath != null ? string.Join("\\", wmiNamespacePath) : string.Empty);
m_scope = new ManagementScope(strWmiPath, options);
m_scope.Connect(); // that is missing in your version
....
var commandLine = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} {1}", fileName, arguments);
var remoteCmd = new ManagementClass(m_scope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), null);
var inParams = remoteCmd.GetMethodParameters("Create");
        inParams["CommandLine"] = commandLine;
        inParams["CurrentDirectory"] = null;
        inParams["ProcessStartupInformation"] = null;
remoteCmd.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
```